# TPUEstimator on GCMLE "InternalError: Job "master" was not defined in cluster"

Tags: tensorflow, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-ml

I am trying to use GCMLE with TF version 1.8 following the instructions on this [guide](https://cloud.google.com/ml-engine/docs/tensorflow/using-tpus).

For TF 1.8 they say:

```
tpu_cluster_resolver = tf.contrib.cluster_resolver.TPUClusterResolver(
FLAGS.tpu,
zone=FLAGS.tpu_zone,
project=FLAGS.gcp_project)

config = tpu_config.RunConfig(
    cluster=tpu_cluster_resolver,
    model_dir=FLAGS.model_dir,
    save_checkpoints_steps=max(600, FLAGS.iterations_per_loop),
    tpu_config=tpu_config.TPUConfig(
        iterations_per_loop=FLAGS.iterations_per_loop,
        num_shards=FLAGS.num_cores))
```

I am then passing these to a TPUEstimator/train_and_evaluate() as follows:

```
estimator = tpu_estimator.TPUEstimator(
    use_tpu=True,
    model_fn=model_fn,
    config=run_config,
    params = params,
    train_batch_size = params.train_batch_size,
    eval_batch_size = params.eval_batch_size,
    )

tf.estimator.train_and_evaluate(estimator, train_spec, eval_spec)
```

For 1.7 they separately say to use a different configuration with a 'master' flag. However, when I run the above 1.8 instructions on GCMLE with `--runtime_version` set to 1.8, I am getting the following traceback error which suggests `InternalError: Job "master" was not defined in cluster`

```
Traceback (most recent call last): File "/usr/lib/python2.7/runpy.py", line 174, in _run_module_as_main "__main__", fname, loader, pkg_name) File "/usr/lib/python2.7/runpy.py", line 72, in _run_code exec code in run_globals File "/root/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/trainer/task.py", line 585, in <module> run_experiment(params) File "/root/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/trainer/task.py", line 127, in run_experiment tf.estimator.train_and_evaluate(estimator, train_spec, eval_spec) File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/estimator/training.py", line 439, in train_and_evaluate executor.run() File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/estimator/training.py", line 546, in run getattr(self, task_to_run)() File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/estimator/training.py", line 601, in run_master self._start_distributed_training(saving_listeners=saving_listeners) File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/estimator/training.py", line 719, in _start_distributed_training self._start_std_server(config) File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/estimator/training.py", line 707, in _start_std_server start=False) File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/training/server_lib.py", line 147, in __init__ self._server_def.SerializeToString(), status) File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/errors_impl.py", line 519, in __exit__ c_api.TF_GetCode(self.status.status)) InternalError: Job "master" was not defined in cluster
```

This is confusing because documentation says not to use `master` so I'm not sure what is going wrong?

Comment: The Guide has been updated [1]. Now only Cloud ML Engine runtime versions 1.8 to 1.9 are available. Do you still have the issue with these newer versions with the newest instructions?

[1] https://cloud.google.com/ml-engine/docs/tensorflow/using-tpus

Answer (score 0):

TPUEstimator is invoked using estimator.train(input_fn=train_input_fn, max_steps=next_checkpoint) and estimator.evaluate()

[Reference](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/contrib/tpu/TPUEstimator)

tf.estimator.train_and_evaluate(estimator, train_spec, eval_spec) only works on CPU/GPU.